# How many neurons does a perceptron have?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

This is a classical visualization of the perceptron learning model, though I don't know where it comes from originally.

[image]

My question is How many neurons does this perceptron have? My guess is N+2, N+1 for inputs, another 1 for output. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

The above network takes numerical inputs `X1`,`X2`,.., `Xn` and has weights `w1` ,`w2` and `wn` associated with those inputs. Also, there is another input 1 with weight `w0` (called the bias unit) associated with it. Also this is one neuron.

This is what a bias unit does:

> Bias is to provide every node with a trainable constant value (in addition to the normal inputs that the node receives).

The output is the weighted sum. Something like this:

f(x)=x1*w1+x2*w2+xn*wn+1*w0

to learn more check this, explains it very well http://117.239.79.250/moodle/pluginfile.php/6283/mod_resource/content/1/ANN1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A perceptron itself is a type of Neuron. In the figure the four inputs aren't neurons but just 4 inputs to a single neuron (perceptron). Also, the step function circle isn't n extra neuron. This step function calculation happens inside the perceptron where the weighted sum is calculated.

So what you see in the figure is a single neuron with its components broken down into fundamental parts.